# How to convert Elo rating to 5 star rating system?

Tags: python, list, math, rating, percentile

We have a Elo rating system (such as, as following) for the players in a video game and want to convert it to 5 star rating ranging from [3.00, 5.00]. The conversion should maintain the following four constraints. That is we want to make sure, the rating are 'well distributed' among players.

- 0 - 25 % of the players get => 3.0 - 3.5
- 25 - 50 % of the players get => 3.5 - 4.0
- 50 - 75 % of the players get => 4.0 - 4.95
- 75 - 100 % of the players get => 4.95 - 5.0

Example Elo rating and the required converted five star rating:

```
elo_ratings = [1295, 1497, 1014, 967, 1021, 1034, 1162, 1198, 1374, 1242, 1292, 1096, 1339, 1365, 1188, 1075, 1344, 1040, 1334, 1513, 1362, 1038, 1177, 1190, 1583, 1551, 1558, 1245, 1202, 1285, 1171, 1223, 1274, 1514, 950]

#ranging from 3 to 5
five_star_ratings = [3.52, 4.10, 3.2, ...]
```

Can anyone help or provide some information on the math or implementation?

Comment: sure that's a possible solution. But if the Elo rating is right/left skewed, then simply dividing into four sub-interval will place majority of the players at a certain ratings. For example, if Elo rating is right skewed, may be, majority of the players will get [4.5, 5.0] rating. But we want to create a good distribution of the rating among the players @JohnColeman , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple of functions in numpy for this - [np.percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) and [np.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

### Code:

```
import numpy as np

elo_ratings = [1295, 1497, 1014, 967, 1021, 1034, 1162, 1198, 1374, 1242, 1292, 1096, 1339, 1365, 1188, 1075, 1344, 1040, 1334, 1513, 1362, 1038, 1177, 1190, 1583, 1551, 1558, 1245, 1202, 1285, 1171, 1223, 1274, 1514, 950]

rankings = [3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.95, 5.0]

boundaries = np.percentile(elo_ratings, [0, 25, 50, 75, 100])

ratings = np.interp(elo_ratings, boundaries, rankings)
```

### Output

```
>>> ratings
array([4.4536036 , 4.98130435, 3.17877095, 3.04748603, 3.19832402,
       3.23463687, 3.6460177 , 3.80530973, 4.95456522, 4.        ,
       4.42792793, 3.40782123, 4.83018018, 4.9526087 , 3.76106195,
       3.34916201, 4.87297297, 3.25139665, 4.78738739, 4.98478261,
       4.95195652, 3.24581006, 3.71238938, 3.7699115 , 5.        ,
       4.99304348, 4.99456522, 4.02567568, 3.82300885, 4.36801802,
       3.68584071, 3.9159292 , 4.27387387, 4.985     , 3.        ])
```

Comment: That's very close, thanks @CDJB , can you suggest the range, as I am getting a lot of player in the range from [4.75, 5.0] from the histogram plot

Comment: That's really up to you - you can just change the star ratings boundaries (`rankings = [3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.95, 5.0]`) and the percentile boundaries (`[0, 25, 50, 75, 100]`) to match the spread you want your data to have.

Comment: I mean https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kIbVsOoP92U1tPnZx22FD6IuDoxCu8BR

Comment: Well yes, as you have 25% of your players with a rating from 4.95 to 5. What result do you expect to get?